# Distribution of random variable

Tags: probability

I need help with this problem:

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of i.i.d$\sim $Uniform$(\{0,\dots,9\})$ random variables.

What is the distribution of $$X= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n 10^{-n}$$

My intution is that $X \sim$Uniform[0,1].

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Good intuition, let's try and pin it down.  Suppose $a,b \in [0,1]$ with $a \le b$.  What is the probability $a \le X \le b$?  Any special cases we can show quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, I'm going to prove this using characteristic function:

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k10^{-k}$$
Then we have that $0 \leq S_n\leq 1$ and $S_n \to X$ a.s. so $X$ is well define and we have that $$\phi_n(t) =E(e^{itS_n}) \to E(e^{itX})=\phi(t)$$ by the dominated convergence theorem or simply because $S_n \to X$ in distribution.

By independence we have that $\phi_n(t)=\prod_{k=1}^nE(\exp(itX_k10^{-k}))$ 
and $$E(\exp(itX_k10^{-k}))=\sum_{j=0}^9 \frac{\exp(itj10^{-k})}{10}=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{j=0}^9 [exp(it10^{-k})]^j=\frac{\exp(it10^{-k})^{10}-1}{10(\exp(it10^{-k})-1)}=\frac{1}{10}\frac{\exp(it10^{-(k-1)})-1}{\exp(it10^{-k})-1)}$$

Then by cancelation we have that $$\phi_n(t)=\prod_{k=1}^nE(\exp(itX_k10^{-k}))=\frac{e^{it}-1}{10^n(e^{it10^{-n}}-1)} \to \frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$$
The last limit is classic and can be computed by L'Hôpital.

Then $$\phi_X(t)=\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}$$

Which is the characteristic function of a uniform random variable, hence $X\sim$Uniform(0,1).